# How to check if Object inside List of List is empty or null?

Tags: java, list, collections

I have something like `List<List<UsersDetails>> userList`. If I debug to see its value it's giving `[[]]` i.e., `List<UsersDetails>` is empty and `List<List<UsersDetails>>` is also empty. Is there a way to check if `List<UsersDetails>` is empty without iteration?

I tried `userList.sizeOf`, `userList.empty()` functions and  `userList==null` operator but all are giving false.

Comment: Correction: if the output is `[[]]` then `userList` is not empty. It contains one element, which happens to be an empty list. How do you want to treat `[[], []]` (i.e. a list that contains two empty lists)? Should that be the same as an empty list or a list containing an empty list?

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check each element in the "outer" list you have to iterate over it **somehow**. Java 8's streams would hide this from you, though, and provide a slightly cleaner syntax:

```
boolean allEmpty = userList.stream().allMatch(l -> l == null || l.empty());
```

Comment: **Without iteration** is specified in question.

Answer (score 2):

There is not. There is:

```
if (userList.isEmpty() || userList.get(0).isEmpty()) { ... }
```

But mostly if the notion: "This a list of lists where the list of lists contains 1 list, but that list is empty" is something you should consider as 'empty', you're using the wrong datastructure. You haven't explained what you are modelling with this `List<List<UsersDetails>>` but perhaps if you elaborate on that, some other data type in java.* or perhaps guava would be far more suitable. For example, maybe a `Map<Integer, UsersDetail>` is a better match here (mapping a user's ID to their details).

Comment: You added 2 list to list. first one is **empty** , but other one is **not empty**. It will fail in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own `List` that simply delegates to e.g. `ArrayList` but prevents `null` or empty lists from being added:

```
public class NonEmptyUserList implements List<List<UserDetails>>{

  private ArrayList<List<String>> mDelegate = new ArrayList<>();

  public void add(int index, List<UserDetails> element) {
    if (element == null || element.isEmpty()) {
      return;
    }

    mDelegate.add(index, element);
  }

  public boolean add(List<UserDetails> element) {
    if (element == null || element.isEmpty()) {
      return false;
    }

    return mDelegate.add(e);
  }

  public List<UserDetails> set(int index, List<UserDetails> element) {
    if (element == null || element.isEmpty()) {
      return null;
    }

    return mDelegate.set(index, element);
  }

  public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends List<UserDetails>> c) {
    boolean changed = false;
    for (final List<String> list : c) {
        changed = changed || add(list);
    }
    return changed;
  }

  public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends List<UserDetails>> c) {
    boolean changed = false;
    int startIndex = index;
    for (final List<String> list : c) {
        add(startIndex, list);
        changed = changed || (list != null) && !list.isEmpty();
        startIndex++;
    }

    return changed;
  }

  // delegate all other methods required by `List` to mDelegate
}
```

Using this list you can be sure no `null` or empty values will be present and thus you can use:

```
NonEmptyUserList userList = new NonEmptyUserList();
userList.add(null);
userList.add(Collections.emptyList());
userList.isEmpty(); // returns true

List<UserDetails> subList = new ArrayList<>();
subList.add(null);

userList.add(subList);
userList.isEmpty(); // returns false
```

If you want to handle sub lists with only `null` elements as empty as well you will need to extend the above implementation. This is however the only solution I can currently imagine that doesn't involve iterating over the list's elements. But I'd not really recommend this solution. I just wrote it down to show you what might be possible.

I personally think the answer provided by @Mureinik using streams is most favorable.